# MINING AT LOW HASH RATE

Tags: gpu-mining, hashrate, mining-profitability

I'm very new to digital coin mining and I'm now just exploring this thing. I've got a rather outdated computer, and I'm now trying to mine monero with Wolf Miner. My current hash rate is around 35 h/s, which is, I assume, very low. So, I've got two basic questions:
1. With this hash rate, is it even worth the trouble to mine monero? Electricity does not count, as it is very cheap in my country, but my GPU and RAM become very loaded when I put the miner on, so I cannot do that 24/7, as I need my computer for other tasks. And what I'm worrying about is that if I need around, say, two years to mine XMR0.1, this will be just a waste of time...
2. I've been mining for around 2 days and got 250 shares. Is there any way to figure out how much XMR I have mined so far? I did not get paid to my monero wallet yet, of course, as it looks like I have mined a tiny fraction of a coin, but I still would like to know at least the approximate amount.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Dont waste your time with this H\s.